# How to enable the RENDER X extension on a minimal Ubuntu install with Lubuntu desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, xorg, tightvncserver

I installed a headless Ubuntu server (16.04 LTS) in a VM at a hoster. Later I wanted to run Mathematica on it (V11.2), this made it necessary to install a GUI. 
Which I did with the command `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends` and then rebooted the system.

My problem is that Mathematica needs the `XRENDER` extension but the X Server that comes with Lubuntu and the LXDE desktop does not support this extension. According to `xdpyinfo` only the following extensions are supported:-

```
BIG_REQUESTS
MIT-SHM
MIT-SUNDRY-NONSTANDARD
SHAPE
SYNC
XC-MISC
XTEST
```

It may be relevant that I run `tightvncserver` on the VM to access the desktop GUI remotely.

Question 1: how can I enable the `XRENDER` extension gently, without reinstalling the whole VM or recompiling the X server?

Question 2 [out of academic interest]: why on earth is this extension not enabled by default? It has been part of X since 2000...

Thank you.